# Attic Fan Box Vapor Barrier

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, junction-box, vapor-barrier

This past weekend I installed a ceiling fan to replace an already existing light fixture. I had to replace the plastic electrical box from when the home was built in 1992.

I am unable to get into the attic for this specific fixture as it's in a spot that I am physically unable to reach due to the layout of my attic and the support beams so I used a retrofit Saf-T Brace rated for ceiling fans.(see below) I'm guessing this box was installed before the drywall was put up because of the location it's at, there really is no way for a person to fit into this small corner of the attic.

When I went to install the brace bar, I realized there is a vapor barrier bubble around the already existing ceiling box with blown in insulation on top of it. It's a 6 mil poly sheet which I am assuming is just stapled and caulked on. I went ahead and cut a small hole on the side to make the brace bar fit through it, secured the bar, installed the box and installed the fan.

I now realize I should have fixed the vapor barrier but since I cannot access it from above - what is the best course of action? I don't really want to have to cut a bigger hole and repatch drywall if I don't have to. Could I use some fire retardant spray foam to seal it up by taking the fan down, removing the box and blowing some in there? Is it even a cause for concern?   [image]

Answer (score 1):

A penetration of this barrier is not of concern. Forget about it. It is probably not a vapor barrier, but is there to keep the blown in insulation from working its way into the box and around the box.

In new construction *all* the boxes are placed on the framing before the drywall is installed.

Comment: I noticed the wiring entering the original box I replaced was just poked through the barrier with no seal as well so that makes sense then.